# Yocto: how to add out-of-tree Device driver?

Tags: compilation, yocto, device-driver

First of all I should say I am a complete newbie to the Yocto world.

I have a working environment that produces my uboot+kernel+rootfs.

I need to add a (complex) driver I have as a subdirectory.

This driver can be compiled natively in the standard way:

```
here=$(pwd)
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$here/bcmdhd modules CONFIG_BCMDHD_PCIE=y CONFIG_BCMDHD=m CONFIG_BCM4359=y
```

I have seen [Integrate out-of-tree driver in kernel and rebuild yocto project image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41614079/1714490) and I have read [Yocto Kernel Development Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html).

I tried to follow directions:

- Created a directory in `.../recipes-kernel` beside `linux` dir.
- Copied the source directory in it.
- Created a `.bb` file.

The resulting source tree is:

```
recipes-kernel/
├── kernel-modules
│   ├── kernel-module-bcmdhd
│   │   └── bcmdhd
│   │       ├── include
│   │       │   ├── include files
│   │       ├── Kconfig
│   │       ├── Makefile
│   │       └── other source files
│   └── kernel-module-bcmdhd_0.1.bb
└── linux
    ├── linux-imx-4.1.15
    │   └── imx
    │       └── defconfig
    └── linux-imx_4.1.15.bbappend
```

My BCM89359-mod_0.1.bb contains:

```
SUMMARY = "Integration of Cypress BCMDHD external Linux kernel module"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"
inherit module
SRC_URI = "file://bcmdhd"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be enough as running bitbake results in no compilation attempted.

I am quite plainly missing something, but I'm unable to understand what.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Uppercase are forbidden, rename your recipe kernel-module-bcm89359_0.1.bb and add it to `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS`

Comment: @Nayfe: I tried several combinations, but my module is not compiled. If I add it to MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS (shouldn't be necessary, I need it in MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS) compilation fails because: "Can't install packagegroup-core-boot-1.0-r17@imx6qpsabreauto: no package provides kernel-module-bcm89359". I suspect I need to add it somewhere else, but I'm unable to understand where :(

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following source tree:

```
recipes-kernel/
├── kernel-modules
│   ├── kernel-module-bcm89359_0.1.bb
│   └── kernel-module-bcm89359
│       └ bcmdhd
│         ├ Kconfig
└── linux
    ├── ...
```

(For the record)
*You can add your module to `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-bcm89359"` to local.conf or machine configuration. Also, you can add `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD = "bcm89359"` to load your module automatically.*